# Can we capture every visualization the user uses in Spotfire?

Tags: tibco, spotfire

I am working on spot fire and wanted to improve my dashboard performance. For that, I thought to store whatever the user uses on every dashboard, whether its the Bar chart or Scatter plot or Pie chart, even the filter user is using. Please do note, I have used Spot fire Web Player to integrate Web and dashboards.

I have already implemented User Action Control from Spot fire Server, but that is not providing the user actions on Spot fire Web player.

Is it possible to store this information?

TIA.

Comment: Have you set up logging to the ACTION_LOG table on your application server?

Comment: Yes. I have selected all the categories which have postfix of "_wp". I am only concerned with user interactions on web player. Is there some other way to save user engagement on dashboard?